# Accuracy of NSEvent timestamp for input events (keyboard/mouse)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, timestamp, nsevent

In Cocoa, NSEvents have a timestamp property which returns a timeinterval representing "The time when the event occurred in seconds since system startup."  I am writing an application which needs exactly this information- precisely when the user presses keys.  But I am worried that the timestamp might not be accurate enough.  Timeinterval itself has sub-millisecond precision, which is great.  Is there any documentation that indicates whether or not the sub-millisecond precision is used to provide accurate timestamps for NSEvents that represent keyboard and mouse inputs?

If I had to guess at apple's implementation, I would hope that the timestamp on the NSEvent might be generated soon after a hardware interrupt, which would be fantastic.  However I could also imagine a system which polls for keyboard/mouse inputs and only populates the timestamp field when the next poll interval comes around and reads the inputs.

Thanks very much for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find Apple's [Cocoa Event Handling Guide: Event Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) document a useful read. From that:

> Before it dispatches an event to an application, the window server processes it in various ways; it time-stamps it, annotates it with the associated window and process port, and possibly performs other tasks as well.

This seems to indicate the Window Server, which lives between the kernel and the application layer, applies the timestamp... though it is possible it reads metadata that was generated at a lower level in order to do this.

I would think the best way to get a better sense of this would be to write an app that records timestamps of key down/up events and look for exact matches in adjacent events. If you see several events in a row with (nearly) identical timestamps, it's more likely they were queued in some buffer before they got timestamped. If there is enough of a gap between adjacent events, it's more likely getting stamped closer to the hardware event.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the link.  Your recommendation for how to get a feel for the performance of the system is a good one.  I do wish there was more detail available about the window server event queue and how it is populated.  In an ideal world the metadata that you mention or as the article says "other information" about the keypress includes something like a system uptime stamp from when the event record is generated and passed to the window server.